# How to pick a trained model instance when its performance fluctuates a lot?

Tags: r, cross-validation, model-selection

I have a dataset that I have to perform a regression task. I split the dataset into 80% for training and 20% for validation.

```
train.index <- sample(N.rows, N.rows * 4/5, F)
train.data <- data[train.index,]
val.data <- data[-train.index,]
```

I used the GBM in R which has the parameters specified (and other take defaults). However, this applies to any kind of algorithms with a grain of randomness embedded.

```
train.model <- function(train.data, val.data)
{
    # 1) model <- gbm(formula = /* ... */, data = train.data, n.trees = 1000, interaction.depth = 3, n.minobsinnode = 5, shrinkage =  0.01, distribution = "gaussian")
    # 2) predict via model on val.data
    # 3) calculate error
}
```

Suppose I executed train.model with the same train.data and val.data every time, and I do it about 50 times. The error (Mean absolute error) percentile is about 5-10%, which is rather high. I could select the best model out of the 50 runs, but this assumes I have a validation set which I do not use as training set.

My question is this:
**Suppose I am using all the data for training (normal cross validation practice), how could I tell if the model is performing poorly and avoid these major fluctuations?**

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I need a clarification. I do not understand what you meant by "I executed train.model with the same train.data and val.data every time, and I do it about 50 times. The error (Mean absolute error) percentile is about 5-10%, which is rather high". It is not possible that repeating an experiment with the same data you obtain different results.